# how to load variables from inherited class function in python

Tags: python, oop

i want to ask about how to load variables from inherited class function in python

this is example of the first class

```
class Shape:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        description = "This shape has not been described yet"
        author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
        def area(self):
            return self.x * self.y
        def perimeter(self):
            return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
        def describe(self,text):
            self.description = text
        def authorName(self,text):
            self.author = text
        def scaleSize(self,scale):
            self.x = self.x * scale
            self.y = self.y * scale
```

and, this is the second class

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = x
```

of the two classes listed above, I would like to take the variable 'x' from 'Square'.
I'm still learning about how to take a variable from this case.

I've searched the internet, but still do not get it. 
thank you for your help

Comment: So you want to use x from Shape in Square?

Comment: so ... what's the problem with this code?  There are places where it could be improved, but I don't see any immediate _problems_...

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. It's my fault.  I mean, I would like to take the variable x from Square.

Comment: @Aditya: And what exactly is your problem doing that? Show us the code you want to write, and where you get stuck.

Comment: Stop asking the same way again and again; evidently, it's not as clear as you think it is. Provide actual code examples to demonstrate what happens now, and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: @abarnert and jonrshape: I just want to learn, how to debug the program. I want to try to call the variable (from outside the program). Because I want to know the value of the variable, without changing the code. I am very sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe And, i'm sorry if asking questions that already exist. Maybe you can show me the link of the existing questions. Thank you

Comment: No, I mean stop just saying *"I would like to take the variable `x` from `Square`"* - find another way of putting it, as it's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to call the base class constructor.

In Python 3:

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self,x):
        super().__init__(x, x)
```

In Python 2 (also works in 3):

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self,x):
        Shape.__init__(self, x, x)
```

Comment: You don't **have** to call it like this, but I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. It's my fault.  I mean, I would like to take the variable x from Square. Not from Shape.. Really sorry. but, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Matthias: I think Miguel Prz was interpreting the "take the variable 'x' from 'Square'" question as "get the variable `x` out of the `Square` class and into the base `Shape` class where it belongs". At least that's how I interpreted it between the first clarification/repetition and before the second one. And this is a perfect answer for that question. (And, as you say, even if that isn't the OP's question, it's a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

First, whatever your problem, I think you want to make the change in Miguel Prz's answer and use `super` to pass the values up to the base class instead of creating the attributes directly in `Square`. (And I thought that's what you were asking for—it effectively takes the variable `x` out of the `Square` class and puts it in the base class `Shape` where it belongs. But I guess not.) Anyway, let's ignore that part and make another guess.

> I would like to take the variable 'x' from 'Square'

Maybe this means you want to access the value of the variable `x` from an instance of `Square`? If so, that's just "dot syntax", as in most other languages:

```
>>> myshape = Square(10)
>>> print(myshape.x)
10
```

It doesn't matter where you do it, even in some function that has no idea it's dealing with a square, the code is the same: `whatever.x`. For example:

```
>>> def area(rectangle):
...    return rectangle.x * rectangle.y
>>> mysquare = Shape(10)
>>> print(area(mysquare))
100
```